# Superset native filter date

Tags: apache-superset

I'm trying to add a native filter for dates on a superset dashboard but i can't find a way to format these dates.[image: SupersetFilterDate]

So I have two problems : i'd prefer to display 01/06/2023 rather than 2023-06-01
and 2023-01-01 appears with only the year displayed (2023)

I've tried timestamps and field in the db but it's the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  `DATETIME_FORMAT` (supported in some databases like

MySQL):

```
    SELECT DATETIME_FORMAT(your_date_column, '%Y/%m/%d') AS formatted_date
FROM your_table;
```

Or `TO_CHAR` (for PostgreSQL):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(your_date_column, 'YYYY/MM/DD') AS formatted_date FROM
your_table;YYYY
```

Replace `your_date_column` and `your_table` with the actual column and table names in your database.

To display with only the year when the day and month are January 1st:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM your_date_column) = 1 AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM your_date_column) = 1
            THEN TO_CHAR(your_date_column, 'YYYY')
        ELSE TO_CHAR(your_date_column, 'YYYY/MM/DD')
    END AS formatted_date
FROM your_table;
```

Comment: Thank you. The only problem is that now, dates are sorted by day, then month then year. which is not very good.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that the filter in itself doesn't allow real date sorting so, if i have my date written "dd/mm/yyyy" il will be sorted by day first. If i want it sorted by year/month/day, i have to write it that way (which is not very user friendly :-) )

Comment: Thanks too for the problem with january but i have worded it wrong : i wanted it written "01/01/2023" but, if i dont format the date data, only the year is displayed in the filter (as in the screenshot). Anyway your answer with to_char solves this too.